# Asp.net Kendo Editor , CustomTemplate add css class to <body>

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

In examples that are provided in telerik website, I found how to add custom template (for example for changing background of text).
which is like this:

```
 @(Html.Kendo().Editor()
                .Name("editor")
                .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 100%;height:250px,font-family: IRS" })
                .Resizable(resizable => resizable.Content(true))
                .Tools(x => 
                    .FontSize(item => item
                        .Add("12px","12px")
                        .Add("14px", "14px")
                        .Add("16px", "16px")
                        .Add("18px", "18px")      
                    )
                    .CustomTemplate(ct => ct.Template("<label for='templateTool1' style='vertical-align:middle; margin-top:5px;'>Dir:</label> <select id='templateTool1' style='width:70px'><option value=''>none</option><option value='rtl'>RTL</option><option value='ltr'>LTR</option></select>"))
                    .CustomTemplate(ct => ct.Template("<label for='templateTool2' style='vertical-align:middle; margin-top:5px;'>pFont:</label> <select id='templateTool2' style='width:70px'><option value='Verdana'>Verdana</option><option value='BYekan'>B Yekan</option><option value='IRS'>IRS</option></select>"))

                )
                .ImageBrowser(imageBrowser => imageBrowser
                    .Image("~/Content/UserFiles/Images/{0}")
                    .Read("Read", "ImageBrowser")
                    .Create("Create", "ImageBrowser")
                    .Destroy("Destroy", "ImageBrowser")
                    .Upload("Upload", "ImageBrowser")
                    .Thumbnail("Thumbnail", "ImageBrowser")
                )

        )
```

and

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#templateTool1").kendoDropDownList({
                change: function (e) {
                    $("#editor").data("kendoEditor").body.style.direction = e.sender.value();
                }
            });
            $("#templateTool2").kendoDropDownList({
                change: function (e) {
                    $("#editor").data("kendoEditor").body.style.fontFamily = e.sender.value();
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

When I run this code everything works well, but for the second custom template which is dropdown for selecting fonts, for first select (**Verdana** font) editor changes the font by adding style to `<body>` tag, but for the second and third choice the font doesn't change.
the 2nd and 3rd are fonts that I add to project by :

```
 @font-face
```

So I decided to add a css class to `<body>` element of editor that applies a custom font to all text, but I don't know how the **jquery format** should be.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

i changed jquery , like this

```
$("iframe").contents().find("body").addClass(e.sender.value());
```

and now i can add css class